# $new = new self($data); with private functions and even variables oO?

Tags: php, oop, scope, stdclass

I have a strange behavior in my php 5.3

i have a class wich dous this in a function

```
       $new = new self($data);
        $new->setServiceManager($this->service);
        $new->cacheInstance();
```

BUT the function cacheInstance is a private function....

```
private function cacheInstance()
    {
        foreach ($this->data as $name => $class) {...}
    }
```

Can some one give an explanation why the hell can this be used like this? shouldn`t this method be private aka unaccessible from outside?

UPDATE:

ok now im totally lost... i can even acess the private variables of the instance... like what the ... this has to be some intended behavior, can somone point me in a direction?

Comment: `new self()` says of course that you are in that class. So because you are IN the class/object you can access its private.

Comment: can you provide more code, because right now, I don't see a problem. If you can create a new instance with new self() it means you are in the class context, so everything looks fine to me

Comment: It sounds like the class is calling a constructor and not the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can create a class instance with new self() it means you are in the class, and of course you can access private properties an functions. This snippet is taken from the PHP Docs ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php))

```
/**
 * Define MyClass
 */
class MyClass
{
    public $public = 'Public';
    protected $protected = 'Protected';
    private $private = 'Private';

    function printHello()
    {
        echo $this->public;
        echo $this->protected;
        echo $this->private;
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
echo $obj->public; // Works
echo $obj->protected; // Fatal Error
echo $obj->private; // Fatal Error
$obj->printHello(); // Shows Public, Protected and Private
```

IN YOUR CASE:

```
class Cache {
    private $service = null;

    private function cacheInstance()
    {
        foreach ($this->data as $name => $class) {}
    }

    public function setServiceManager( $service ) {

    }

    public function myTest( $data ) {
        $new = new self( $data );// you are in the class, so you can call new self()
        $new->setServiceManager($this->service);
        $new->cacheInstance();
    }
}
$cache = new Cache();
$cache->service; //Fatal error: Cannot access private property

$data = array();
$cache->myTest( $data );// working

$cache->cacheInstance();// not working
```

Comment: Thank you. makes sense... in a wierd way :P

Answer (score 1):

`private`, `protected` and `public` accessibility works on class level, not on object level.

While it may seem counter intuitive first, this is not your usual PHP weirdness.

#### It's the same in other OOP languages, like [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6)

> Note that accessibility is **a static property that can be determined at compile time**; it depends only on types and declaration modifiers.

#### and [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx)

> The private keyword is a member access modifier. Private access is the least permissive access level. Private members are accessible only within **the body of the class or the struct in which they are declared**

*(highlights added)*

### Explanation

The accessibility is a mechanism to hide *implementation details* from *code in other classes*, not for encapsulation of objects. Or as it's stated in the Java specs, accessibility can be determined at compile time, i.e. there cannot be a runtime violation because it's a different object.

It makes sense, if you look at the difference between private and protected. For private members, an object does not have access to its own members if they are declared in a parent class. Sounds weird? That's because the terminology is wrong. The  **class** does not have access to privates of its **parent class** (i.e. it may not use them).

Now in your method, you use private variables within the same class. There is no need to hide this implementation detail from yourself, the author of this class, no matter what the objects are at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

ok... wierd like quantum mechanics... have been pointed in RL to the answer

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

QUOTE:

> Objects of the same type will have access to each others private and
>   protected members even though they are not the same instances. This is
>   because the implementation specific details are already known when
>   inside those objects.

Talking about wierd...